# CFT description of polynomially degenerate, critical spin-chain

Tags: symmetry, conformal-field-theory, spin-chains

For length $L$ spin chains described by conformal field theories, there's a nice a way to extract the central charge via fitting the following ansatz for the entanglement entropy of the ground state:
$$S(l) \sim \frac{c}{3} \log \left(\frac{L}{\pi} \sin\left( \frac{l \pi}{L} \right) \right) + const$$

This ansatz is expected to hold for large $l$ and $L$.

---

However, I was imagining a critical spin chain that had many ground states (say, polynomially many in $L$), such as a chain with a non-abelian continuous symmetry like $SU(2)$. (Note that the symmetry alone is not enough to ensure degeneracy, but it's often a necessary ingredient.) With many ground states, its not clear to which state one should apply the ansatz above; one should be able to change the prefactor of the log depending on the choice of superposition.

This leads me to two questions. First, can a critical spin chain with polynomial-in-$L$ ground-state degeneracy induced by a continuous non-abelian symmetry like $SU(2)$ ever be described by a CFT? Second, if there exist such curious spin chains, which ground state should be chosen when trying to extract the central charge using the $S(l)$ ansatz above?

---

A point of evidence against the first question - I believe the Heisenberg ferromagnet at the $SU(2)$ invariant point is not described by a CFT, as it has a low-energy dispersion that is quadratic instead of linear. However, perhaps this doesn't rule out a more exotic example.